# Javascript get all the most frequent characters in a string

Tags: javascript

I need help on how can I get **not** just **one** but **other** most common character/letter in a string.

my code only works on getting one of the common character.

but when more than one character are equally common only one are returned.  I would like it to return two character if two character are common.

```
const x = mostCommonCharacter("abbbcddefffg");
console.log(x); // result is *b*
```

if *b* and *f* are most common I would like to return *bf*

```
  function mostCommonCharacter(str) {
  const charHolder = {}; // { a: 1, b: 3, c: 1, d: 2, e: 1, f: 3, g: 1 }

  str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .forEach(char => {
      if (char != " ") {
        if (charHolder[char] == null) {
          charHolder[char] = 1;
        } else {
          charHolder[char] += 1;
        }
      }
    });
  let highest_num = 0;
  let letter = "";
  for (const key in charHolder) {
    if (charHolder[key] > highest_num) {
      highest_num = charHolder[key];
      letter = key;
    }
  }
  return letter;
}
```

but It only return one most common character which is "*b*"

what I need is for it to return "*b*" and "*f*" because both of them are most common. and not just *b* is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `highest_num` and then again iterate through object and get those letters for which count is equal to `highest_num`

```js
function mostCommonCharacter(str) {
  const charHolder = {}; // { a: 1, b: 3, c: 1, d: 2, e: 1, f: 3, g: 1 }

  str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .forEach(char => {
      if (char != " ") {
        if (charHolder[char] == null) {
          charHolder[char] = 1;
        } else {
          charHolder[char] += 1;
        }
      }
    });
  let highest_num = 0;
  for (const key in charHolder) {
    if (charHolder[key] > highest_num) {
      highest_num = charHolder[key];
    }
  }
  let res = '';
  for(let k in charHolder){
    if(charHolder[k] === highest_num){
      res += k;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(mostCommonCharacter("abbbcddefffg"))
```

A shorter version of the code can be obtained by using `reduce()` and `Math.max`

```js
function mostCommonCharacter(str) {
  const charHolder = str
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .split('')
                      .reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1, ac), {});

  let max = Math.max(...Object.values(charHolder));

  return Object.entries(charHolder).reduce((ac,[k,v]) =>v === max ? ac + k : ac, '');
  
}

console.log(mostCommonCharacter("abbbcddefffg"))
```

Comment: In the first example, there isn't really a need to iterate through twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with a simple change. Just add the letter to "letters" if it is equal to "highest_num".

```
  let highest_num = 0;
  let letters = "";
  for (const key in charHolder) {
    if (charHolder[key] > highest_num) {
      highest_num = charHolder[key];
      letters = key;
    } else if (charHolder[key] === highest_num) {
      letters += key;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add an 'else' in front of your second if or you will get the first highest letter twice

Comment: Also, I'm aware that OP's code could be optimized, but that wasn't part of the question. I tried to focus on the minimum viable solution that provided the output desired (a string, "bf").

Answer (score 0):

Please find a more compact approach where you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to get the {letter: frequency} map in an object from the string after splitting it into an array.

Then use the `Object.entries` to get the most frequent and second frequent letters after sorting the entries of [key, values]:

```js
const x = mostCommonCharacter("abbbcddefffg");
function mostCommonCharacter(str){
  const dict = str.split("").reduce((acc, ele) =>{
    acc[ele] = (acc[ele] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const letters = Object.entries(dict).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).map(a => a[0]);
  return letters.length > 1 ? letters.slice(0, 2).join("") : letters.length > 0 ? letters[0] : null;
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution involving an algorithmic approach using `hashmaps`.

```js
var a = 'abbbcddefffg';

const counter = (str) => {
  var ch = {};
  for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    
    if(str[i] in ch) {
      ch[str[i]] += 1
    } else {
      ch[str[i]] = 1
    }
  }
  return ch;
}

let sorted = (list) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(list).sort( (a,b) => b[1] - a[1] )) 

let counterInSorted = sorted(counter(a));

let getXMostOccuring = (stringObj, x) => {
  return Object.keys(stringObj).slice(0,x).join('');
}


console.log('First x elements occuring frequently');
console.log(getXMostOccuring(counterInSorted,2));

console.log(sorted(counter(a)))
```

**This approach will provide with the frequency of each character in a sorted manner. 
You can now decide to get 'x' most occurring characters.**